# Building 32bit libraries opencv

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, cmake

I recently downloaded and built opencv in my 64-bit Windows machine using `cmake`. All the binaries are included in the `install` folder and it contains only the folders as shown below:
[image]

I don't know how to config cmake to produce binaries for x86. I'm asking this, because I'm using **Qt Creator 32bit with MinGW** and I'm getting problems while linking and compiling the code. What's the proper way to do the build? I'm using `mingw` compiler suite.

**Note: The downloaded package contains the pre-built binaries for `x86` but there are none for MinGW, but only for Visual Studio.**

Comment: Afaik you can choose the used compiler in CMake. if you clear the cache the first step should be a drop down menu with compiler choices.

Answer (score 6):

Steps for mingw from with `cmake-gui` from this [guide](https://zahidhasan.wordpress.com/2014/08/19/qt-5-3-1-64-bit-mingw-windows/). We could also do this easily on command prompt with `cmake` and `-m32` option. But using `cmake-gui` will give you more idea about the options available  for opencv configuration and bring you in better position if you want to customize opencv build tomorrow (  like enabling java wrapper or OpenCL etc  ).

1. Start cmake-gui.
2. Set `source path` to downloaded opencv directory and `build path` to your choice as in image

   [image]
3. Click `Configure` button and specify generator as mingw makefiles as
   in image

   [image]
4. Choose compilers ( here we choose 32 bit ) as in image and click `Finish` button.

[image]

5. An options page will be listed.

   5.1.  Edit `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` to change the install location if you want to.

   5.2. Select `ENABLE_CXX11` if it isn't already selected.

   5.3. Change other options only if you are  familiar with them. Then click `Configure` again and then click 'Generate` to generate make files.
6. Modify `opencv\sources\modules\videoio\src\cap_dshow.cpp` and add this define at the top of the file:

   ```
   #define STRSAFE_NO_DEPRECATE
   ```
7. In command prompt( at build path ) type `mingw32-make` ( add `mingw32-make` folder to `PATH` if required )
8. On completion, type `mingw32-make install`