# How OpenCV 3.0 can be used with Qt 5.4 on windows7 32 bit?

Tags: qt, opencv3.0

Is there any way to use prebuilt binaries of the two?
If not, how openCV 3.0 can be compiled from the source using MinGW compiler for windows 32 bit platform. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://wiki.qt.io/OpenCV_with_Qt

Comment: Compilation and installation of OpenCV using MinGW (available within Qt) creates only x64 folder within the install directory but not x86. My operating system is 32 bit. What could be causing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28122457/building-32bit-libraries-opencv

Comment: I tried several times. I followed all the steps but still can't compile for native Windows 7 32 bit. It generates only install\x64. Please help!

Comment: I don't know where to go from here. If it was VisualStudio I'd tell you to change the configuration of the project generated by CMake to 32 bit and compile. Have you built correctly the project generated by CMake?

Comment: I used the commands 'mingw32-make' and 'mingw32-make install'. There were a few warnings. But in the end everything looks fine. Only problem is it's not compiling for 32 bit.

Comment: Are you sure that is not compiled in 32, even if in folder x64?