# OpenCV 32bit available for vs 2019?

Tags: c++, opencv, gcc, g++

I'm doing a project in C++ where I need to combine openCV and Zbar. I download both Zbar en Opencv from there original locations, but zbar is in 32bit, and openCV is in 64 bit.

I did find this [post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28122457/building-32bit-libraries-opencv), where he is using MinGW with 32bit, but mine didn't come with 32 bit gpp.exe and g++.exe. I downloaded two extra tar.xz files from MinGW [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Base/gcc/Version6/gcc-6.3.0/): "GCC-core-6.3.0-1-mingw32-bin.tar.xz" and "GCC-c++-6.3.0-1-mingw32-bin.tar.xz" and extracted them into mingw32 but when I run CMake GUI with those gcc.exe and g++.exe I get an error that mingw32-g++.exe is broken. Full error message [can be found here](https://pastebin.com/N1niixWJ).

So my question is there a pre-compiled version of OpenCV available for 32bit, and that is usable in c++?

thank you in advance for the help

```
ignore this, StackOverflow needs code in this post???
```

Comment: Are you using MinGW or VS 2019? You should be able to compile OpenCV using CMake

Comment: @macroland I installed MinGW (all the basic packages) and then I tried to compile OpenCV with Cmake GUI.

Comment: THen make sure the version of the OpenCV you have downloaded is compatible with the version of the GCC you are using.

Comment: hmmm, and where may I find this information. I have installed the lastest OpenCV (4.1.2) and MinGW 6.3

Comment: zbar for win 64 [does exist](https://github.com/ryokash/ZBarWin64)

Answer (score 0):

[OpenCV x86 pre-built binaries for MinGW](https://github.com/huihut/OpenCV-MinGW-Build/tree/OpenCV-4.1.0)

Makefile example to use it:

```
CC         =   g++
CFLAGS     =   -c -Wall -std=c++17
OBJECTS    =   $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
INCLUDES   =   -IC:\\Users\\xxxxx\\OpenCV-MinGW-Build\\include
LIBDIRS    =   -LC:\\Users\\xxxxx\\OpenCV-MinGW-Build\\x64\\mingw\\bin
LIBS       =   -lopencv_core411 -lopencv_highgui411 -lopencv_imgcodecs411 -lopencv_imgproc411
SOURCES    =   main.cpp dog.cpp
EXECUTABLE =   dog
ARGS       =   

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC)  $(OBJECTS) $(LIBDIRS) $(LIBS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $< -o $@

run:
    $(EXECUTABLE) ${ARGS}

clean:
    del *.exe
    del *.o
```

The path `C:\\xxxx\mingw\\bin` should be added to the system path to run the program.

Comment: I'm not sure if I need to do anything, but there are no lib files included in that download.

Comment: The dll files in `bin` folder is the library syou need to link during build stage.